# Exam Question on Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

For a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, $\int_0^1f^3(x)x^ndx = 0 $ for each integer $n \geq 1$. Prove $\int_0^1f^4(x)dx = 0 $. (where $f^n(x)$ is the nth power of $f$). And hence prove $f = 0$.

I am able to prove the second part i.e. $\int_0^1f^4(x)dx = 0 \Rightarrow$ $f = 0$, but the first part eludes me.

Any hints are welcomed.
Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's approximate $f^3$ by polynomials $p_n$.
$$
\| f-p_n \|_\infty \leq \frac1{n}
$$
$f^3$ is continuous, so we have $M>0$ that
$$
\| f^3 \|_\infty \leq M
$$
Now
$$
0 = \int f^3 p_n = \int (f^3 - p_n + p_n) p_n = \int (f^3 - p_n)  p_n + \int p^2_n
$$
from this we get inequality
$$
\left| \int p^2_n \right| \leq   \int  \left|(f^3 - p_n)  p_n \right| \leq 1 \cdot \frac1{n} \cdot (M+1) \rightarrow 0 \text{  as } n\rightarrow \infty
$$
because $p_n$ converge uniformly to $f^3$ we get that
$$
\int p^2_n \overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} \int f^6 = 0
$$

I showed that $\int f^6 = 0$ and not $\int f^4 = 0$ but from this point the argument for $f=0$ should be the same.